# Reactive forms Angular formGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am building a form with reactive form, but i have some nested group inside group, and for that nested group i have only validation required on input. The problem I have is that inside that nested group, i have to have validation that if user enters in one input something, others inputs in that group are not required anymore.

This is what i have for now, i have tried to add **Validators.required** instead 
**RequiredValidatonOnlyOne()**.
Is it possible to add some custom validation that will validate that user has enters something in just one input

```
 this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      lastName: [{ value: '', disabled: false }, [Validators.maxLength(50), Validators.required]],
      phones: this.formBuilder.group({
        phone: [{ value: '', disabled: false }],
        phone2: [{ value: '', disabled: false }],
        mobile: [{ value: '', disabled: false }],
      }, this.RequiredValidatonOnlyOne())
    });


  private RequiredValidatonOnlyOne(){
    return (controlGroup) => {
      const controls = controlGroup.controls;
      if (controls) {
        const theOne = Object.keys(controls).find(key => controls[key].valid);
        if (!theOne) {
          return {
            atLeastOneRequired: {
              text: 'At least one should be selected'
            }
          };
        }
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

Comment: *Is it possible to add some custom validation that will validate that user has enters something in just one input?*: Isn't that exactly what you did with the RequiredValidatonOnlyOne() custom validator options? Is there a problem with the above code? If so, what is the problem?

Comment: can you share code of your `RequiredValidatonOnlyOne()` so we can help? it is custom validator and probably something wrong with it.

Comment: Added RequiredValidatonOnlyOne

Comment: So the problem is that the code doesn't compile, right? Have you read the error message from the compiler? Have you read the documentation of FormBuilder.group(). Its second argument is not a validator. Read the documentation. https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#group

Comment: Code compiles, but validation on phones does not works :(

Comment: Form is always valid even if you dont enter nothing in phones fields

Comment: Again, read the documentation of Form.group(). It expects an argument of type AbstractControlOptions, not a validator. It's really as simple as that.

Comment: And your validator is incorrect, too. It should check that at least one control has a value. Not that at least one is valid. They're all valid, since none has a validator.

Comment: I know that i am wrong, i have tried, if you know the answer please write it, thanks @JBNizet

Comment: Have you read the documentation I linked to? What don't you understand? By reading it, explain what should the second argument of the group() method look like? It's written in the documentation, so you just need to copy and paste it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RequiredValidatonOnlyOne()
  {
    return (controlGroup:FormGroup)=>{
      const controls = controlGroup.controls;
      let valid:boolean=false;
      return Object.keys(controls).find(key => controlGroup.get(key).value)?null
             :{requiredOne:"required one"}
    }
  }
```

Sorry and updated: in Angular 8 formBuilder has changed, use `{validator:this.RequiredValidatonOnlyOne()}` to add a validator to a formGroup, see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yaqqoq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      lastName: [{ value: '', disabled: false }, [Validators.maxLength(50), Validators.required]],
      phones: this.formBuilder.group({
        phone: [{ value: '', disabled: false }],
        phone2: [{ value: '', disabled: false }],
        mobile: [{ value: 'aaa', disabled: false }],
      }, {validator:this.RequiredValidatonOnlyOne()})
    });
  }
```

You need search a control with value, not if is valid (valid are always, because the controls has not validators inside -and they must not have any-)

Comment: No, form returns form.valid TRUE, even if i didnt enter nothing in inputs

Comment: Sorry, I forget that in Angular 8 to give validator to a formGroup it's used {validator:your-validator}, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

the approach i see is `clearValidators()`. set `(change)` event listener on all controls. call a function on change, pass the `formcontrol` itself as argument and clearvalidators of other controls execept for this one. if input is empty then `setvalidators()` again on all controls.